# How to determine which activity begins when i launch application?

Tags: android, launch

I want know how i can determine which activity begins when i launch application ?

I have two Activity. MainActivity and Activity2. Which is the way i can code my application start every time in MainActivity ?

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
   <activity
```

Comment: Exactly! If this question is resolved, please mark it so.

Answer (score 3):

Check out your AndroidManifest.xml file. In there you have each of your activities listed, then you can simply specify which one you'd like to be the default startup by adding this "intent-filter" shown below.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Check my manifest, it is like you show but my application still start sometimes on Activity2.

Comment: Did you change the name of the Activity to the right one?
android:name=".MainActivity" is your first activity called "MainActivity"?

Comment: Names are correct, i have "MainActivity.java" and "Activity2.java".

Comment: Try Build>>>Rebuild your project. Otherwise if that doesn't work, you'll have to post your code, because it should work.

Comment: I would add that, both activities have own layout called "activity_main.xml" and "activity2.xml", if it has no meaning..